# How to search and replace with a counter-based expression in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, counter, replace

Is there a way to insert the value from some sort of counter variable in Vim `:substitute` command?

For instance, to convert this document:

```
<SomeElement Id="F" ... />
<SomeElement Id="F" ... />
<SomeElement Id="F" ... />
```

to this resulting document:

```
<SomeElement Id="1" ... />
<SomeElement Id="2" ... />
<SomeElement Id="3" ... />
```

I imagine, the command would look like so:

```
:%s/^\(\s*<SomeElement Id="\)F\(".*\)$/\1<insert-counter-here>\2/g
```

I am using a very recent Windows build, from their provided installer. I strongly prefer not to install any additional tools. Ideally, I'd like to also avoid having to install scripts to support this, but I'm willing to, if it is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Vim wiki instructions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers) seems to be the easiest solution (at least for me).

Example below replaces all occurences of `PATTERN` with `REPLACE_[counter]` (`REPLACE_1`, `REPLACE_2` etc.):

```
:let i=1 | g/PATTERN/s//\='REPLACE_'.i/ | let i=i+1
```

To answer the question it might look like this:

```
:let i=1 | g/SomeElement Id="F"/s//\='SomeElement Id="'.i.'"'/ | let i=i+1
```

#### Alternative solution

If anyone is interested in a solution with `%s` syntax I would advise to look at the @ib. answer which is:

```
:let n=[0] | %s/Id="\zsF\ze"/\=map(n,'v:val+1')/g
```

Comment: Better than the first answer because it doesn't mess with keybinds, and shows what's going on in a much simpler way. It is identical to the version submitted by anubina, but also links to semi-official documentation.

Comment: But I don't understand, how to use it with `'<,'>` aka current selection. The pattern for find-replace looks odd *(e.g. `g` in the beginning, `s` is in the center, what's going on??)*, is there a way to make it work with the usual `s/from/to` command?

Comment: I just hate how the regex syntax here is different than the one used in %s vim substitutions

Comment: @jmarceli Can you please the `%s` equivalent in your answer ?

Comment: What would be an easy way to have padding with the numbers? So 1, 2, 3 would instead be 001, 002, 003?

Answer (score 23):

It is possible to have a counter using the substitute-with-an-expression
feature (see `:help sub-replace-\=`). Unfortunately, since the
`\=` construct allows only expressions, the `:let` command cannot
be used, and therefore, a variable cannot not be set the usual way.

However, there is a simple trick to change the value of a variable in
expression if that variable is a list or a dictionary. In that case,
its contents could be modified by the `map()` function.

In such a manner, substitution for the case described in the question
would look as follows:

```
:let n=[0] | %s/Id="F"/\='Id="'.map(n,'v:val+1')[0].'"'/g
```

The tricky part here is in the substitute part of the replacement.
Since it starts with `\=`, the rest of it is interpreted
as an expression by Vim. Thus, `'Id="'.map(n, 'v:val+1').'"'`
is an ordinary expression. Here a string literal `'Id="'`
is concatenated (using the `.` operator) with return value
of the function call `map(n, 'v:val+1')`, and with another
string, `'"'`. The `map` function expects two arguments:
a list (as in this case) or a dictionary, and a string containing
expression that should be evaluated for each of the items in the given
list or dictionary. Special variable `v:val` denotes an individual
list item. So the `'v:val+1'` string will be evaluated to a list item
incremented by one.

In this case, we can even simplify the command further:

```
:let n=[0] | %s/Id="\zsF\ze"/\=map(n,'v:val+1')[0]/g
```

The `\zs` and `\ze` pattern atoms are used to set the start and
the end of the pattern to replace, respectively (see `:help /\zs`
and `:help /\ze`). That way the whole search part of the substitute
command is matched, but only the part between `\zs` and `\ze` is
replaced. This avoids clumsy concatenations in the substitute
expression.

Either of these two short one-liners completely solves the issue.

For frequent replacements, one can even define an auxiliary function

```
function! Inc(x)
    let a:x[0] += 1
    return a:x[0]
endfunction
```

and make substitution commands even shorter:

```
:let n=[0] | %s/Id="\zsF\ze"/\=Inc(n)/g
```

Comment: +1.  I am going to leave the first accepted answer, since it was first, and works (and might also be useful in different scenarios), but I will admit that this is slightly closer to what I had in mind.  Kudos!

Comment: @Merlyn Thanks!  For me, this is almost idiomatic way of substituting when a counter is necessary (adding line numbers in listing, replacing ids, etc).

Comment: What's with all the extra single quotes?  I asked in the other answer, but still can't figure it out (by staring at it) :)

Comment: @Merlyn I've added more explanations to my answer.

Comment: @lb: Very good answer I must say. However when I tried above in my gvim I get this error: `E730: using List as a String
E15: Invalid expression: 'Id="'.map(n, 'v:val+1').'"'` Any ideas?

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for noticing this!  I've lost `[0]` after the map call when I retype the command into the answer textbox.   Because the counter is wrapped in list it could not be concatenated with string as is.  So it's necessary to subscript the item or to convert the whole (one element) list into string by `join` or `string` functions.  The answer is corrected.

Comment: By the way, if you do not need to concatenate additional strings to counter, you can use the list itself.  Hence, `%s/smth/\=map(n, 'v:val+1')/g` will work correctly.

Comment: @Merlyn @anubhava I've managed to simplify the substitute command to avoid (in this case unnecessary) concatenations in the substitute expression.

Comment: @ib: Wow, this question has turned up a wealth of information. `\zb` and `\ze` will get rid of a ton of zero-width assertion overhead in a lot of my searches.  I wish I could post-answer-bounty as a tip ;)

Comment: An unwanted line break is somehow inserted after each substitution when I apply this solution.

Comment: @bongbang: Only in the second, simplified version of the command (the one that uses `\zs`, `\ze` without the helper `Inc` function).

But yeah, Vim adds a newline after each item when rendering a list in `\=` subsitutions, even if there is only one item in it. I don’t remember it being that way when I wrote the answer—or maybe it was and it’s just a mistake nobody noticed somehow.

I’ve added the missing `[0]` subscript in that command (the first and third versions of the command already had it—the former explicitly and the latter implicitly, within `Inc`). Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 13):

Hmm this it little tricky one. Here is what I got so far. Try these 2 map command in a vim session:

```
:nmap %% :let X=1<cr>1G!!
:nmap !! /^\s*<SomeElement Id="F"<cr>:s/F"/\=X.'"'/<cr>:let X=X+1<cr>!!
```

Once that is there press `%%` to start the fun part :)

It makes your given file as:

```
<SomeElement Id="1" ... />
<SomeElement Id="2" ... />
<SomeElement Id="3" ... />
<SomeElement Id="4" ... />
```

#### Explanation:

**First** nmap command is mapping following sequences to keystrokes `%%`:

- initializing variable X to 1
- moving to start of first file
- calling another mapped keystroke `!!`

**Second** nmap command is mapping following sequences to keystrokes `!!`:

- Search for next occurrence of pattern `^\s*<SomeElement Id="F"`
- If above pattern is found then search and replace `F"` by variable `X` and a quote `"`
- increment the vim variable X by 1
- Recursively call itself by making a call to `!!`
- Single dot `.` is used for concatenation of strings in vim, very similar to php

This recursive calls stop when pattern `^\s*<SomeElement Id="F"` is not found anymore in the file.

Comment: +1.  This is very helpful!  My actual file has lines besides these, though.  How do I advance to the correct line before executing `s/F"/\=X.'"'/`.  Also, what does the `.'"'` part do?

Comment: Cool, it worked, once I figured out to (more or less) replace `j` with `:/F"<cr>` :)  Can you add a blow-by-blow of your script?  I understand it, but I think it would be a great thing to add to the answer.

Comment: Added explanation and did some modification to 2nd map command to make sure to replace `F"` by incrementing numbers only in the lines matched by pattern `^\s*<SomeElement Id="F"`

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that dot (.) is used for concatenation Of strings in vim, very similar to php.

Comment: I believe using using a recursive macro instead would be much more vim-like. Mapping over the default execute register command (`@@`) aka execute macro is a probably unwanted. You might also consider using `nmap` instead of `map` so your mappings don't bleed into your other modes.

Comment: @Peter Rincker: Thanks for good suggestions. I edited my answer to use `%%`instead of `@@` and used nmap instead of map.

Comment: @anubhava I would map one of the function keys as they will not collide (`:h map-which-keys`).

Answer (score 7):

Very simple solution. I've had to do this several times.

```
:let i=1 | g/^\(\s*<SomeElement Id="\)F\(".*\)$/s//\=submatch(1).i.submatch(2)/ | let i=i+1
```

Based off of the following tip. http://gdwarner.blogspot.com/2009/01/vim-search-and-replace-with-increment.html

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your vimrc or execute it in your current session:

```
function! Inc(x) 
  let a:x[0] += 1 
  return a:x[0] 
endfunction

function IncReplace(pos, behind, ahead, rep) 
  let poss=a:pos-1 
  let n=[poss] 
  execute '%s/' . a:behind . '\zs' . a:rep . '\ze' . a:ahead . '/\=Inc(n)/g' 
endfunction
```

Then execute `:call IncReplace(1, 'Id="', '"', 'F')`

The first argument is the number you want to start from, the second is what you want to match behind the number, the third is what you want to match ahead of the number and the fourth is what you actually want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [plugin increment.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=842) will help