# How to replace CSV column separators with numbered labels in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, csv

I want to replace a series of pipeline characters with different values. How would I do this with regular expressions?

Example:

```
This | is | a | sentence
And | this | is | the | second | one
```

Final result:

```
This new is new2 a new3 sentence
And new this new2 is new3 the new4 second new5 one
```

Comment: Please, rephrase your question adding additional details about desired replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If substitution values differ only in the numbers at the ends, use the command

```
:let n=[0] | %s/|/\='new'.map(n,'v:val+1')[0]/g
```

(See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942360/gvim-find-replace-with-counter/5944828#5944828) to the question "[gVim find/replace with counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942360/gvim-find-replace-with-counter)" for
detailed description of the technique.)

In case of substitution values that differ essentially from each other, change
the command to substitute not a serial number of an occurrence, but an item of
a replacement list with that number as an index.

```
:let n=[-1] | %s/|/\=['one','two','three'][map(n,'v:val+1')[0]]/g
```

To perform the substitutions on every line independently of each other, use
the `:global` command to iterate one of the above commands through the lines
of a buffer.

```
:g/^/let n=[0] | s/|/\='new'.map(n,'v:val+1')[0]/g
```

Similarly,

```
:g/^/let n=[-1] | s/|/\=['one','two','three'][map(n,'v:val+1')[0]]/g
```

Comment: What about multiple lines. I want the same changes throughout multiple lines. adding %s^|/$\...rest of the replace commands, doesnt seem to work.

example
FROM:
This | is | a | sentence
This | is | second | sentence
This | is | third | sentence

TO:
This new is new2 a new3 sentence
This new is new2 second new3 sentence
This new is new2 third new3 sentence

Comment: @help:  It is easy: just use the `:global` command to iterate the routine over the lines.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Sweet thanks. Still learning about vim commands and regex, so I didnt know of such command. I thought the g flag at the end meant global? again thanks for the help.

Comment: @help:  The `g` flag of the `:substitute` command prescribes to replace all occurrences in the line, while the `:global` command executes an Ex command on the lines within range of lines where a pattern matches (see `:h :s`, `:h s_flags`, `:h :g`).

Answer (score 0):

Define a function:

```
fun CountUp()
  let ret = g:i
  let g:i = g:i + 1
  return ret
endf
```

Now, use:

```
:let i = 1 | %s/|/\="new" . CountUp()/g
```