# How to achieve the increase with vim replace?

Tags: vim

I want to replace the code below:

```
<input name="rating" id="rating">
<input name="rating" id="rating">
<input name="rating" id="rating">
<input name="rating" id="rating">
...
<input name="rating" id="rating">
```

to:

```
<input name="rating1" id="rating1">
<input name="rating2" id="rating2">
<input name="rating3" id="rating3">
<input name="rating4" id="rating4">
...
<input name="rating100" id="rating100">
```

How to achieve the increase with vim replace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I'd start with just one line:

```
<input name="rating1" id="rating1">
```

Then [record a macro](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#q) <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> that [yanks the whole line](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#yy) <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>, [pastes it below](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#p) <kbd>p</kbd> and [increments the two numbers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#CTRL-A) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>[<kbd>w</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#w)<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>. Stop recording the macro <kbd>q</kbd>.

Then [run the macro](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#@) 98 times <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

But then I've spent too much time playing [VimGolf](http://vimgolf.com/)!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it is always the current line number you want to append to the word "rating", you can use this:

```
:%s#rating\zs#\=line(".")#g
```

Comment: This is quite an assumption, given this is clearly HTML code and there would therefore be a `<head>` section above.

Comment: Very nice! I just tested and it seems that you can do `...\=line(".")+10...` (replace 10 with whatever your starting line number is). +1 for teaching me something new. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple and efficient technique for implementing counter-based
substitutions in Vim.  I have proposed it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944828/254635) to the question
"[gVim find/replace with counter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5942360/254635)".  To understand the idea, see that
answer as well as my answers to related questions: "[Using Vim, how do you use
a variable to store count of patterns found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8073780/254635)" and "[CSV search and
replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7366430/254635)".

Similarly, the issue described in this question can be solved by the command

```
:let n=[0] | %s/="rating\zs\ze"/\=map(n,'v:val+1')/g
```