# How can I replace value with a series of increasing number in VsVim?

Tags: vim, vsvim

I want to replace this part with a series of increasing number in VsVim.

Like so：

```
std::map<std::string, int> monthMap = {
    {"Jan", 0}, {"Janurary", 0}, {"Feb", 0}, {"February", 0}, {"Mar", 0}, {"March", 0}
};
```

I want to substitute all 0 for 1, 2, 3...

```
std::map<std::string, int> monthMap = {
    {"Jan", 1}, {"Janurary", 1}, {"Feb", 2}, {"February", 2}, {"Mar", 3}, {"March", 3}
};
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Also, if you don't know Vim, why bother with a Vim emulator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079772/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+replace+increase

Comment: also a lengthy discussion can be found here https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/how-to-replace-each-match-with-incrementing-counter/12869#12869