# Search and replace with increment in vim

Tags: vim

I have a json file which looks as follows:

```
{
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "model.Model",
        "fields": {
         "data1": "example",
         "data2": "example"
      }
    },
   {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "model.Model",
        "fields": {
         "data1": "example",
         "data2": "example"
      }
    },
   {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "model.Model",
        "fields": {
         "data1": "example",
         "data2": "example"
      }
    },
```

etc....

I would like to search and replace "pk": 1 and increment the value. so my file would look like:

```
{
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "model.Model",
        "fields": {
         "data1": "example",
         "data2": "example"
      }
    },
   {
        "pk": 2,
        "model": "model.Model",
        "fields": {
         "data1": "example",
         "data2": "example"
      }
    },
   {
        "pk": 3,
        "model": "model.Model",
        "fields": {
         "data1": "example",
         "data2": "example"
      }
    },
```

So far I have tried:

:let i=1 | g/"pk": 1/s//="pk": .i./ | let i=i+1

to search for the "pk": 1 pattern and replace it using a counter, but I have a syntax error somewhere and am hitting a brick wall.

Any help / suggestions would be very much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vim let search and replace with increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398235/vim-let-search-and-replace-with-increment)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+replace+increment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
:let i=1 | g/"pk": \zs\d\+/ s//\=i/ | let i+=1

 \zs .............. start pattern
```

To fix your attempt do:

```
:let i=1 | g/"pk": 1/s//\='"pk": ' .i/ | let i=i+1
```

As you can see the first mistake was a missing backslash at the substitution portion `\=`. The second was using a second concatenation at the end `.` which would make vim try to concatenate the variable with nothing. The third was forgetting to put the `"pk":`  into 'single quotes' otherwise you would ended up with pk unquoted. Remember here we are concatenating a string with a number.

Comment: This looks good, but shouldn't the ':' be outside the double-quotes in the replacement section of the solution?