# Is there something like $nth / counter in regexp (in the context of text replacement in visual studio code)?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace

I got a long array of anonymous function in a javascript file and I want to add a name before the functions.
I want to go from that

```
[function(){...}       ,function(){...}      ,...,function(){...}]
```

to that

```
[function foo_1(){...},function foo_2(){...},...,function foo_850(){...}]
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code that allow searching and replacing strings using regexp.
I got no problem writing the regexp except for the substitution token that would mean this is the Nth match for your search.

Something like $Nth that will return 1 for first occurence of your search in text. Then 2 and so on.

Or even better $Nth(45) that will start at 45 then 46...

Does such a token exist ?

Comment: Most programming languages allow you to use a function as the replacement, and it can increment a variable. I don't know how you would do this in a text editor.

Comment: You'll need to check the VSCode documentation to see if it provides something like this, it's not something provided by regexp in general.

Comment: Regex does not have the concept of a match counter. You'd need to use an external counter. Here is how you can do that with the vim editor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656861/7475450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

With normal VSC selection select all the `function()` parts you need.

- open Find Dialog
- search for: `function(`
- select all occurrences: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can limit the find to a selection. First select the part, in the Find Dialog the first thing to do is select `Find in Selection` (one of the buttons or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

Execute the command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)**

- the first Match Expression press: <kbd>Enter</kbd> (accept default `.*`)
- for the Generator Expression: `function foo_{{=i+1}}\(` or `function foo_{{=i+45}}\(`
- if you like what is generated: <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- if you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> the operation is terminated

If you have to do this a lot you can create a key binding with the Regex strings predefined and optionally use the input dialogs to modify the predefined strings

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f7",  // or any other key combination
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "regexTextGen.generateText",
    "args": {
      "originalTextRegex": ".*",
      "generatorRegex" : "function foo_{{=i+1}}\\(",
      "useInputBox" : true
    }
  }
```