# Vim 8 - How do I re-number my list after reordering the list - manually or automatically?

Tags: sorting, vim

Say I have a list like this:

```
1. apple
2. banana
3. orange
4. plum
```

Now I want to reorder them by deleting/cutting lines and pasting them in the right spot, but the numbers are no longer in order:

```
2. banana
1. apple
4. plum
3. orange
```

How can I re-number this list or have Vim handle a numbered list automatically? (**I'll add my answer, but I believe there should be a faster way**)

Comment: If you ignore that the list was ordered before, it's a duplicate of [How to search and replace with a counter-based expression in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942360/how-to-search-and-replace-with-a-counter-based-expression-in-vim)

Comment: The fact that it was ordered before is why it's not a duplicate. In other text editors (e.g. Word) you can reorder items in a list and the numbering is handled automatically. Your link does contain answers that I could use for this situation, but they are way more complicated and do not take into account a previous ordering.

Comment: Why should the previous ordering be taken into account? Do you need to preserve holes in numbering, or something? Strictly by your question, your renumbering is just... numbering. (Also, "highlight the entire list again" is just `gv`, so you could map your entire process into a macro or a very simple command or mapping.)

Comment: @Amadan Are you suggesting that every time I move a line to a different spot within a list, the best and only way *is* manually deleting/resetting the numbers and then redoing the entire numbering? This is not an uncommon edit that people do, surely there's a better way that's automated or a one keyboard shortcut to trigger a re-numbering. (I didn't know about `gv` that's helpful, thank you).

Comment: Who said "manually"? I specifically said "very simple command or mapping". Here is a mapping based on your procedure: `nnoremap <leader>rl <cmd>'<,'>s/^\d\+/0<cr>gvg<C-a>`. Select your list, hit `<leader>rl` (for "renumber list"; but you can obviously set the map trigger to whatever you want) and there it is. If you have a blank line above the list and a blank line below (and no blank lines inside), `vap` will select the whole list for you; you can even add it to the mapping if you wish (for more speed and less versatility).

Comment: Alternately, no, people don't often renumber lists in random documents. I have never done it outside of Markdown. So you can use a plugin that already does what you want there, like e.g. [MkDnFlow](https://github.com/jakewvincent/mkdnflow.nvim) (default binding `<leader>nn`). It is also a bit smarter than my very simple mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One slightly inefficient way is to reset the numbered list to zeros and then recreate them.

For instance, once the list looks like this:

```
2. banana
1. apple
4. plum
3. orange
```

do the following.

1. Highlight list and run `:s/[0-9]*\./0./` to substitute the numbered list for a list all beginning with `0.`

```
0. banana
0. apple
0. plum
0. orange
```

2. Highlight entire list again using `gv` (as suggested in comments) and do `g` and then `<ctrl> + a` to renumber list from 1-n

---

**EDIT April 2nd, 2024** - Based on the suggestion from @romainl in the comments and from community help in these questions ([one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/44517/why-does-normal-gv-keep-removing-one-line-from-my-visual-block) and [two](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/44523/renumbering-in-vim-gc-a-wont-work-in-vimscript-function)), I took my solution above and made a Vimscript function that can be added to a `.vimrc` .

```
vnoremap <C-L> :call ReNumberList()<CR>
function! ReNumberList() range
    execute a:firstline .. ',' .. a:lastline .. 's/[0-9]*\./0./'
    execute "normal! gvg\<C-A>"
endfunction
```

It works by remapping the shortcut `ctrl+L` (`<C-L>`) to the function `ReNumberList()`. That function does the number substitution on the range of lines, re-highlights the range again (with `gv`), and finally does the renumbering with `g\<C-A>`.

With this, you can highlight an out of order list and then type one shortcut to renumber the whole list!

Comment: Well, turn that into a custom command/operator and you have your efficient way.

Comment: If your list has fewer than 10 list numbers, you can skip the substitution by using visual block `<ctrl>+<shift> + v` (then `}` or `j` or `↓` ) to highlight just the list numbers; and then `r0` to set the numbers to 0; then `gv` followed by `g`, `<ctrl> + a` to incement the list.  This has problems, though, if the number of columns in the visual block selection is not uniform.  (Which is why I stipulated "fewer than 10".)

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: this answer assumes that you are doing that in a markdown context.

FWIW, Markdown renderers are generally expected to *ignore* the actual numbers in your numbered list except the first one, which is used as a hint for how the output will be numbered.

This list:

```
2. banana
1. apple
4. plum
3. orange
```

is rendered as:

2. banana
3. apple
4. plum
5. orange

[image: list]

```
<ol start="2">
<li>banana</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>plum</li>
<li>orange</li>
</ol>
```

but this list:

```
1. banana
1. apple
4. plum
3. orange
```

is rendered as:

1. banana
2. apple
3. plum
4. orange

[image: list]

```
<ol>
<li>banana</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>plum</li>
<li>orange</li>
</ol>
```

or maybe:

```
<ol start="1">
<li>banana</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>plum</li>
<li>orange</li>
</ol>
```

***If your ultimate goal is to render your markdown to something else*** (meaning that your `*.md` is only read when editing, not on its own), I would suggest you give up on proper ordering in your source and only use `1.` as a hint for the renderer:

```
1. banana
1. apple
1. plum
1. orange
```

and let it do its magic:

1. banana
2. apple
3. plum
4. orange

[image: list]

```
<ol>
<li>banana</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>plum</li>
<li>orange</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Did OP say they're editing markdown? Must have missed it.

Comment: Assumptions were made.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment, this case is covered by [How to search and replace with a counter-based expression in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942360/how-to-search-and-replace-with-a-counter-based-expression-in-vim). That the list was ordered before is of no consequence. It's not as if those tiny list items carried a memory of their previous ordering.

The request was especially to make it simple.
For a list with only four items, I'd actually just reorder it out-of-place and leave the numbers untouched.

Starting with the list below:

```
1. apple
2. banana
3. orange
4. plum
```

For that, I'd use blockwise Visual mode to select the list items, not the numbers. Put the cursor on the first list item, press `<C-V>`, select all the items by pressing `}$` and cut them with `d`.

For the actual list operations, I'd paste the list items e.g. in a scratch buffer (see [`:help scratch-buffer`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#scratch-buffer)); the bottom of the current buffer will also do nicely.

```
1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 

# somewhere else

apple
banana
orange
plum
```

Reorder the list items to your desired order, do a blockwise Visual selection again and delete them. Then paste them back after the first number of your original list.
Done:

```
1. banana
2. apple
3. orange
4. plum
```

If you ever needed to add to the list, you can append an item to its end and then reorder as outlined above.